# Print all Gmail messages between specific dates

Tags: pdf, printing, gmail, export

Is there a way to print (or export, or save as PDF) all mail messages between specific dates in Gmail?

I realize I could probably do it through an email client, but I would rather be able to through the web interface that I use daily.

Answer (score 1):

[James Ferreira](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109060419131235223303/about) wrote a Chrome App for that and used Google Apps Script for it:

**Gmail Print All PRO**

- [Google Apps Script Examples](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/gmailprintallproisnowavailable)
- [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-print-all-pro/jobhgbnpobdpmpdhcnailgemedfhjbho)

> Gmail Print All Pro is here to help you quickly export messages right
>   to a Google Doc that you can print, save as a pdf, share with others,
>   or store in a way that works for you. Built to be simple to use, all
>   you do is add messages to a Gmail label and run Print All from your
>   Chrome Web Apps screen. This will create a Document in Google Drive
>   containing the content from your messages and you can even choose to
>   have the attachments saved in the same folder.

It used to be free a charge, but nowadays a little fee is required. Program is said to have [22000](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109060419131235223303/posts/RjgmkeU4CGJ) weekly users.

Note: I'm not affiliated to Gmail Print All PRO

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how you would easily print all of the results, but you could find them by searching for:

```
after:2012/01/01 and before:2012/12/31
```

Obviously, you would replace the dates with your own.

Comment: I don't think this is a useful answer without the part about printing.