# Google Apps Script: print, open or download as PDF a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Form that will run a script on submit to dynamically generate a google doc. So far so good.

What I miss is a way to:

- Print the document (open the printing preview in browser)
- Preview document (Google doc preview)
- Download document

Apparently there's no way to let the script interact with the browser. Is this true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is true for server-side code. Some people published Chrome Extensions or used client side code to make it possible to automate some web browser tasks like the one suggested by Jacob Jan Tuinstra on his answer to  [Print all Gmail messages between specific dates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47002/88163)

Related

- [How to get and use a value of a cell in the PDF file name exporting using that script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130025/)
- [Export PDF link sheet ID auto change](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130105/)
- [Custom function to export a google sheet to PDF](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/142382/)