# How to get and use a value of a cell in the PDF file name exporting using that script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I get and use a value of a cell to the PDF file name, when exporting/saving using that script. I would like to use a string written in a cell, I mean, put that information in a variable and automatic use it as the pdf file name. At this moment, when I execute the script, a window is opened and in the file name field there are something like this: "Spreedsheet name" - "sheet name".pdf. And I have to rewrite to the name that I already have in a cell.

```
function ExportPDF() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getSheetId();
  var pagina = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheet + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=' + sheet + '&portrait=false&scale=4';
  var html = "<script>window.open('" + pagina + "');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Open Tab');
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value of a cell in the PDF file name"?

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56215898/7108653

Comment: @Rubén Hi, I would like to use a string written in a cell, I mean, put that information in a variable and automatic use it as the pdf file name. At this moment, when I execute the script, a window is opened and in the file name field there are something like this: "Spreedsheet name" - "sheet name".pdf. And I have to rewrite to the name that I already have in a cell. Thanks!

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Please [edit] your question to add those details as they are key to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you very much for your suggestion. After just a few adjusts that worked very well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the script below, located in https://stackoverflow.com/q/56215898/7108653, like suggested for @Tanaike, and adjusted with just a few things (lines 3, 4 and 5).

```
function downloadSheetAsPDF2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("RECEITA PARA IMPRESSÃO").getSheetId();
  var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('M3').getValue();  
  var filename = valor;


  // Creat PDF file as a temporary file and create URL for downloading.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&portrait=false&scale=4&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(filename);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  var dlUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();

  // Open a dialog and run Javascript for downloading the file.
  var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
  file.setTrashed(true);

  // This is used for closing the dialog.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  var closeHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>google.script.host.close()</script>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(closeHtml, "sample");
}
```