# Custom buttons to trigger the Import or Print in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I am using an HTML function (HtmlService.createHtmlOutput) to show my custom buttons in a popup or sidebar within my google sheets.

But I am simply trying to make custom buttons to invoke the already existing links in the google sheets menu.. Please see my screenshot below.

I have tried this in the HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="triggerButton" nclick="document.getElementById('PrintBtnID').click()" />
```

[image: screenshot of Import and Print link inside menu]

Comment: The Google menu does not reply on html. Have you read [Custom menus in Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms)

Comment: Yes @Tedinoz I have. But this seems to have to be a JS solution that goes outside of an iframe. If that is possible.

Comment: Apologies. I misinterpreted your question. I thought you wanted to make buttons for day-to-day use of the conventional spreadsheet, not in the sidebar/popup.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script doesn't include a way to call Google Document Editors built-in menu actions and I think that it could not be possible to do that from a dialog / sidebar created using the HTML Service because this elements are in an iframe nested inside the the page.

One alternative could be to use user scripts for extensions like Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey

Similar question in Stack Overflow

- [Open print preview dialog programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51999744/1595451) (so afar no answer)

Related

- [Google Apps Script: print, open or download as PDF a Google Doc?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125705/88163)
- [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/1595451)