# Selective printing from a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I work in a school and have a teacher who wants to print multiple tabs from a Google spreadsheet. I have managed to show her how to print the pages she wants in the workbook (File, Print, change "Current Sheet" to "Workbook"),now she wants to exclude parts of those pages so that they do not print. These are cells below the area she wants to print that are part of the whole spreadsheet. In Excel I used to be able to mark the print area. This would be easy if it was just one of the tabs that she wanted to print, in this case there are a number of them. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome. You don't mention how many sheets the user has to print, or how often. But I think you are referring to sheets that might have several hundred/thousand blank rows below the last data row. This is the price of being able to print  the whole workbook by pressing Ctrl+P. Unfortunately a script/macro is out of the question too ([Google Apps Script doesn't include a way to call Google Document Editors built-in menu actions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/142401/196152) ht: @Rubén).  One solution would be to simply delete all the excess blank rows on problem sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets does not have a function to save a print range (as others do) but at print time, you can select the range you wish to print and then click on the printer icon in the toolbar. The printer settings will open showing a representation of what will be printed. Follow the usual instructions from there to complete the printing task. This task can be made easier by declaring a named range under `Data > Named ranges`.

As for printing multiple tabs, this is easily achieved by selecting the printer icon in the toolbar then select Workbook then the drop down against All Sheets which will then allow you unselect as required (the default position is all sheets selected) the sheets in the workbook you do not wish to include.

[image]

The above graphic is from a Workbook containing a number of monthly sheets (months in French) with all currently selected. Untick any not required in this print run and select APPLY after which it will show a representation of what will be printed. Follow the usual instructions from there to complete the printing task.